# replace all links containing the text "edit" with an image except in a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have all the links containing the text "edit" replaced with an image. I want this to happen throughout my site, except in a specific class.

I have this code right now:

```
$('a:contains("Edit")').html("<img src='<%= asset_path 'edit.png' %>'/>").css('display',  
'inline-block');
```

and I have tried:

```
$('a:contains("Edit")').not$("div[class='section-nav']").html("<img src='<%= asset_path 
'edit.png' %>'/>").css('display','inline-block');
```

but that omits the entire action everywhere, not just in the class div I specified.

htlm for specific div that I do not want the image

```
<div id="ideas_navigation" class="section-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/ideas/bpul_dishes/edit">Edit Idea</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

html for the links I do want text replaced:

```
<a href="/ideas/bpul_dishes/edit">Edit</a>
```

Comment: change `.not$("div[class='section-nav']")` to `.not($("div[class='section-nav']"))` you missing brackets / parenthesis .

Comment: your question is not clear. be clear what you want to be done

Comment: can you please post an example of your html - it would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a filter function:

```
$('a:contains("Edit")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('div.section-nav').length == 0;
}).html("<img src='<%= asset_path 'edit.png' %>'/>");
```

The above will only return anchors that contain the word "Edit" that are not within a div with a class of `.section-nav`.

Not sure if the above `.html` will work though (it's taken straight from the code in your example) as there seems to be a lot of single quotes

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WZSzn/1/)

Comment: my html is in my question

Comment: @anmaree The above should work fine with your html - you added it after I had answered.  [New fiddle with updated html structure](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WZSzn/2/)

Comment: @Pete interesting approach.  I think you may want to change closest to parent in case the html for this was ever nested inside another div with the section-nav class.  This happens a lot with menus.

Comment: @kasdega this is the best solution, `closest` will find the parent element no matter how far up the tree where as parent will only get the immediate parent. As the anchor will not be the direct child then closest is the approach to take

Comment: @Pete closest will search all the way up the tree until it finds a match.  Take the case of a menu for instance...
`div class="section-nav">
   <UL>
     <li><div><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></div></li>
     <li><div class="section-nav"><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></div></li>
   </UL>
</div>`

Both anchor tags in this scenario would be ignored because of the enclosing div.section-nav

Comment: @kasdega and your point is? that is exactly what is wanted - any anchors within a div with a class of section-nav should be ignored. Also look at the structure of the html, with your answer (which you have provided with a fiddle with invalid html you will always need the div to be the second parent (which won't happen as you forgot your uls).  What about nested anchors within that menu that may still be within the section-nav?

Comment: @Pete I'm not criticizing at all, I appreciate everyone who at least tries to answer questions especially when they work.  I'm merely making an observation that if you use closest, perhaps a sneaky side effect would be that it will continue to traverse the DOM upward until it finds what its looking for.  We don't know that this is a problem because we only got a partial HTML sample.  My point being that maybe parent().parent()... would be safer but then again maybe it isn't a problem at all.  I just wanted to point out what is happening with closest.

Answer (score -1):

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4frdw/4/)

**jquery**

```
    $('a:contains("Edit")').parent().parent(":not(.section-nav)").html("NEW HTML HERE").css('display','inline-block');
```

Comment: I think that the OP's section-nav class is attached to the div containing the links, not the links themselves, so this will not filter out links within that div.

Comment: this doesn't change anything

Comment: you'll need to tell us anmaree if the "section-nav" class is on the achor tag or on the div containing the anchor tag.  What I have here will change any anchor tags with the word "Edit" in them that do not contain the class "section-nav"

Comment: it is the class that contains the link.. I added html to my question

Comment: changed my answer based on your question updates and posted an example of a fiddle that does what you want I think.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('*:not(div.section-nav) a:contains("Edit")')
    .html("<img src='<%= asset_path 'edit.png' %>'/>").css('display','inline-block');
```

... assuming that what you want is to replace the html and change css for all "Edit" links that are not within the div having the class section-nav.

Comment: this is not for inputs this is for anchor tags - this isn't what he's looking for.

Comment: Why the downvote? This will work. The original typo was fixed within seconds of the original post and it wasn't downvoted until later after it was fixed.

Comment: I down voted.  I'll be happy to change that if you fix it.  It doesn't work.  The first part of your selector gets "All elements that are not a div with a class section-nav" which is basically everything in the DOM that is not <div class="section-nav">